Why did Neo thank Morpheus here?
In real world from The Matrix Resurrections (2021), Neo questions Seq about Morpheus's form:

Neo: What is that?
Seq: An exomorphic-particle codex. It's pretty new. It gives programs
access to this world.  Within limits.
Morpheus: Limits are the domain of the limited.
Neo: Morpheus. Thank you.

Why did Neo thank Morpheus here?
